# How to open a text file and find what is written after a specific word in a line and append that files name to a list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to build an app in Python that will open a file, and find a specific keyword and read what is after that keyword only in that line. If that value matches any element in the input list it should append the said files name (with extension; in this case text.txt) to another list.

This is my code:

```py
input_list=input("> ").split(", ") # The input list
file_list=[] # Where the filenames should be appended

with open("/path/to/file.txt") as current_file:
    for line in current_file:
        if line[5::] in input_list:
            print("It works!")
            file_list.append(current_file)
        elif line[9::] in input_list:
            print("It works!")
        elif line[12::] in input_list:
            print("It works!")
        else:
            print("It doesn't work!")
```

But always prints It doesn't work. Even if there is a match. Let alone append the filename to the list.

Sample file:

```
Value=@3a
Execute=abc
Name=VMTester #line[5::] should remove the "Name=" and also Name could also be "Name[en_us]=" or just "Name[bn]="
Comment=This is a samplefile
```

Sample input:
`VMTester`

Comment: What is in your file and what are you are trying to search?

Comment: can you show sample of file and input

Comment: Should the search stop after the first match? If not, what should happen if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes the search should stop after the first match.

Comment: just saw your edit; you could use `split` to search the line after `=`, see the note in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks ok in principle; it's just that you append a file object to your `file_list` if you do `file_list.append(current_file)`. The `with` context will even close it so no point to do that... Also, you could use `any` to check if any of the `input_list` items is `in` the current `line`. Assuming the seach should stop as soon as a match is encountered, you can use `break` to skip all further lines. A modified version of your code could look like

```py
input_files = ["/path/to/file.txt"] # you can add more files to search here...
input_list = input("> ").split(", ")
file_list = []
extracted_words = []

for file in input_files: # added loop through all files to search
    with open(file, 'r') as current_file:
        for line in current_file:
            if any(w in line for w in input_list):
                print("It works!")
                # append the file name:
                file_list.append(file)
                # append the matched word (strip newline character):
                extracted_words.append(line.split('=')[1:][0].strip())
                break
        print("It doesn't work!") # looped through all lines, no match encountered
```

Comment: I already used the for loop but didn't include it because the for loop was working fine. What you suggested runs but it appends all files that it gets. So yeah...

Comment: @A.Shahir: your question also says that you want to "read what is after that keyword only in that line" - how should that content be handled? appended to another list?

Comment: If there is something like "Name=VMTester" in a line in a text file, I only want to see if  VMTester is in the input list. If it is, then append the **filename** to a list and move on to the next file. Also using the split by equal as you said, that returns nothing to the list.

Comment: @A.Shahir: well, that's expected since you don't actually extract those strings anywhere. made an edit to include that. note: making another list is just an example. you could also implement more sophisticated constructs here, like e.g. namedtuples or a dict.

Comment: My bad. I don't need the extracted string. Here's the thing. If I enter `VMWare Player` as input, lets say, at the end of the script i print `file_list` and its an empty list. (Using `if any(w in line.split("=")[1::] for w in input_list)` instead of `if any(w in line for w in input_list)`). Even though there is a file with `VMWare Player` written in it. If I use `if any(w in line for w in input_list)`, I get all files given to the script.

Comment: you mean "VMWare, Player" (as you split on ",")? if that is the input, `l = "VMWare, Player".split(",")`, and e.g. `line = "Name=VMWare"`, then `any(w in line for w in l) == True` and `line.split('=')[1:][0].strip() == 'VMWare'`. maybe add some `print` statements to see what's going wrong?

Comment: I got it to work. I used `for filename in input_files` and did not change `file_list.append(file)` to `file_list.append(filename)`. Thanks for your help.